# How do I limit registration in my Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application with a registration form, and anyone can register multiple accounts.

I want to limit the registration to one account per IP address. How do I achieve this? I also want to only accept Gmail.

Here is my registration form:

```
<h4> {{ $page_title }} </h4>
<span class="liner"></span>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-12">
         <h4> Registration </h4>
         <span class="liner"></span>
         <div class="widget-content clearfix">
             <form action="{{ route('post-member') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 {!! csrf_field() !!}
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Member Plan</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <select name="price_id" id="" class="form-control" required>
                             @foreach($price as $p)
                             @if($p->id == $pr)
                             <option value="{{ $p->id }}" selected>{{ $p->title }} - {{ $general->currency }} {{ $p->price }}</option>
                             @else
                             <option value="{{ $p->id }}">{{ $p->title }} - {{ $general->currency }} {{ $p->price }}</option>
                             @endif
                             @endforeach
                         </select>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name" required>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" required>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phone</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="text" name="phone" required class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Phone">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <textarea name="address" id="" cols="30" rows="3"
                             class="form-control" required></textarea>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Profile Picture</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="file" name="image" id="" required class="form-control">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Password</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="password" required name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <input type="password" required name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8">
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> Registration</button>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </form>
```

Comment: when a user visits your page, check in your database if the current ip exists. If it doesn't then continue with registration else prompt it to the user

Comment: Check user IP. if it is exists in database then denied user registration.

Comment: Isn't it missing three `</div>` at the end? Have you run a sample HTML page through an HTML validator?